# Login with POST & HTTR with CSFR Token in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to access the following URL in R with **httr** library using the POST function. I need to pull out some currencies rates where the script developed is already developed. I'm having issues in authenticating for having different time periods inside the tool.

```
https://www.oanda.com/fx-for-business/historical-rates/auth/login/
```

I'm using the following code

```
  library(httr)

        Cookie = paste('opc_id=599C877C-7B4C-11E7-A634-FD6593E2D6B9;', 'csrftoken=EJqIgiufV77Nlv4E54mKoFcxhKGJgnO4cdQzUy2ehaayjD5FX21F8MznpHm0o4W5;','sessionid "6bc5s0qnswsue0pxe3st83ezf6m9cdl5;')

    headers = list (
    Host= "www.oanda.com",
        "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0",
         Accept =  "*/*",
        "Accept-Language" = "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Encoding" =  "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Content-Type"= "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        Referer =  "https://www.oand

a.com/fx-for-business/historical-rates",
    "Content-Length" = 64,
    "X-Requested-With" =  "XMLHttpRequest",
    Cookie = Cookie,    Connection= "keep-alive")

    .headers = character(headers)

    par = list (
    email = "user",
    password = "pass",
    redirect=""
    )

    POST("https://www.oanda.com/fx-for-business/historical-rates/auth/login/",body = pars, add_headers(.headers))
```

The result of the last line is below. The script is requiring a CSFR Token, how can I generate it?

```
        <h1>Forbidden 
            <span>(403)</span>
        </h1>
        <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>
        <p>You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.</p>
        <p>If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for &#39;same-origin&#39; requests.</p>
```

The structure of the GET & POST are the following

```
GET https://www.oanda.com/static/sfb/hcc/templates/html/en/popup.login.html?_=1502097958941
    POST https://www.oanda.com/fx-for-business/historical-rates/auth/login/
    GET https://www.oanda.com/fx-for-business/historical-rates/getUser/?_=1502097958942
    GET https://www.oanda.com/fx-for-business/historical-rates/message/messages/?_=1502097958943
    GET https://www.oanda.com/static/sfb/hcc/templates/html/en/banner.expiry.html?_=1502097958944
    GET https://www.oanda.com/static/sfb/hcc/templates/html/en/popup.login.success.html?_=1502097958945
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution resides on simulating a web browser inside R. 
The code for achieving this is the following

```
    library(wdman) #I don't  know if this library is necessary
    library(RSelenium)

    selServ <- selenium(jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.verboseLogging=true"))
    remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "chrome")
    remDr$open()

    ##From here you need to access with your login details inside the browser

    remDr$navigate(url)


    df=remDr$getPageSource()
```

Comment: You can also use chrome in headless mode (currently unix and OSX) see the second method here https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/138